# '￥'記号をtrを使って'/'に変換すると、bashで警告が出るのはなぜですか

Tags: bash, cygwin

初歩的な質問です。Linux勉強中なので、教えてください。
windows上のcygwinでbashスクリプトを書いています。

windowsのファイルパス(例C:\program\hoge)をLinux形式(例C:/program/hoge)に変換しようと思い

```
echo 'C:\program\hoge' | tr '\' '/'
```

を実行したところ、

tr: 警告: 文字列の最後にあるエスケープされていないバックスラッシュは可搬性がありません

とエラー出力が出ました。
何が原因かよく分からずエラーを無視して使っていますが
問題はないでしょうか。

Comment: ちなみにですが、`tr(1)` には `\NNN  character with octal value NNN(1 to 3 octal digits)` と記載されていますので、`echo 'C:\program\hoge' | tr '\134' '/'` とすることもできます。

Comment: ちなみに、cygpathコマンドを使えば、`C:/program/hoge`とか`/c/program/hoge`とかに簡単に変換できます。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\`がエスケープ文字として認識されているからです。
`echo 'C:\program\hoge' | tr '\\' '/'`という風に`\`を`\`でエスケープすればエラーが出なくなります。